# Qt debugging in release mode - all methods not working

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt-creator

I am trying to build my `Qt` app with `MinGW` in `QtCreator` in order to try and debug a release-only crash.

Here is what I put in my `.pro` file (also tried putting it directly into `qmake.conf`):

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -g
```

as well as tried with

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -ggdb
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -ggdb
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -ggdb
```

I tried them separately or together like this:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -g
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -ggdb
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -ggdb
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -ggdb
```

I have also manually edited the generated `Makefile`(`Makefile.Release` to be exact and checked `Makefile.Debug` just in case) to remove the `NO_DEBUG` flag (I don't know why it was being put there) and to make sure the `-g` and `-ggdb` flags are there.

The result of all of this is that the app took almost twice as long to build, however it was exactly the same size as before and didn't have any debugging symbols and trying to debug it didn't succeed.

What else can I do? I know it's possible, but looking for other answers only directed me to using those flags and that didn't help at all(only made build slower)

Comment: Did you try also modifying QMAKE_LFLAGS? It could be that the linker strips debug symbols.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov that makes sense and explains the extra build time, however what flag must I add to the linker?

Comment: Since MinGW is basically GCC, I suspect the same flag should do. At least it's worth to try.

Comment: there is a -export-all-symbols flag, I'll try with that too

Comment: Exporting symbols is one thing (although I thought GCC exports everything by default), and debugging info is another (line numbers and so on). But it shouldn't hurt anyway.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov ok that doesn't seem to help, I still get a small exe with no debug info, any other ideas? I added the same things to QMAKE_LFLAGS

Comment: Not yet. I'll try it tomorrow as I don't have Qt/MinGW at hand right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In qmake.conf (can't recall where this is now) the default behaviour is set as:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = -Wl,-s
```

Where the -s means the linker does away with the symbolic info. So in addition to the flags you have set you need to clear the flags (or overwrite) in QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE. In your case just setting it to empty should do it, so in your .pro file add:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE =
```

**FURTHER  NOTES**

If you add the line `message(QMAKESPEC: $$QMAKESPEC)` to your .pro file, when you run qmake you will see the path for your make spec. Look in the qmake.conf file (it will have includes) and work your way through them.

Assuming you are using windows (because I did not see the -Wl,-s option set in the linux make specs for Qt 5.5.1) then the file in question is:
`<path-to-qt>/5.5/gcc_64/mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf`

Anyway, I did not see any other useful flags set (I am using linux so this was only checked by eye. However if you are worried, then add the following to your .pro file:

```
message(QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE: $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE)
```

To check it before you make changes and then you will have the complete picture of what is going on :)

Comment: and after I clear it I don't add anything new, correct?

Comment: hmm this seems to have impacted my exe in a strange way, now I double click it and nothing happens.  
This is what it shows when I try to debug:  
  
"Debugging starts  
Debugging has finished"

Comment: maybe I'm removing an important linker flag?

Comment: Well, maybe... but in this case I think you are just removing the default flags, then you can add whatever flags after that. Try it, if it works out then worry about the other flags : )   .... but also, looking down, I think @SergeyTachenov's idea is perhaps a better final solution, my answer is really to get you on the right path/get something working : )

Comment: @shortage_radeon Adding a note to answer so you can see what linker options are default for you...

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured it out, and only saw @code_fodder's answer after it. It looks like @code_fodder is essentially right, but I'm adding more details to reflect the precise steps that helped me.

I've specified `qmake` arguments in the Qt Creator project settings like this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-g QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE-=-Wl,-s
```

This essentially adds `-g` to the compiler flags and removes `-Wl,-s` from the linker flags (which strips all symbols). Then **I ran `qmake` and did full rebuild.** After that, debugging sort of worked—as you'd expect for a release build: jumping from line to line in a somewhat random fashion because of the optimizations, but at least it worked.

I'm using 32-bit Qt 5.5.1 with bundled MinGW on a 64-bit Windows 7 system, if that is of any help.

Comment: are you sure about removing -Wl? I read something about "—if the linker is being invoked indirectly, via a compiler driver (e.g. gcc) then all the linker command line options should be prefixed by -Wl"

Comment: @shortage_radeon, `-Wl,-s` is a single option that passes the `-s` (strip symbols) option to the linker. I'm removing the whole `-Wl,-s` thing! Of course it wouldn't make any sense to just remove `-Wl` and leave `-s` alone, but that's not what I'm doing here.